# Incorrect syntax near '\'

Tags: c#, sql

I need to write a program that iterates through a few SQL scripts at a specific path location and executes them. The progress will be incremented on a progress bar, which I still need to do, and the progress will be shown on a `TextBox`. When running the program I get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near '\'.

The code is as follow:

```
public void runScripts()
{
    int lc = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(this.sc, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    this.pgbCopyProgress.Maximum = lc;
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(this.sc);
    DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

    if (!dir.Exists)
    {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(
                "Source directory does not exist or could not be found: "
                + this.sc);
    }

    // Get the scripts in the directory and run them
    FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
    foreach (FileInfo file in files)
    {
        try
        {
            string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Wiehan_Deployer;Integrated Security=True";
            string f = this.sc;
            f = f + @"\" + file;
            FileInfo fl = new FileInfo(f);
            string scripts = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = fl.ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            txtEvents.Text += "\nScript executed successfully." + f;
            lc = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(this.sc, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
            this.pgbCopyProgress.Value = lc;
            this.pgbCopyProgress.Update();
            this.pgbCopyProgress.Refresh();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            txtEvents.Text += ex.Message + "\r\n" ;
            txtEvents.Update();
            txtEvents.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line shows the syntax error?

Comment: And is it *actually* a compile-time error, or an exception?

Comment: the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line

Comment: You are assigning a file-path as `CommandText`, seems to be pointless.

Comment: @naheiwProg ah can you update your question then please to mention that it is a run time error? (it is not explicitely clear) and thus also at which line the error occurs. tnx

Comment: I don't think that file path is considered a proper SQL command.

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter sat a couple of hours and didn't even see that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
cmd.CommandText = fl.ToString();
```

You're passing in the filename as the command text, instead of the text itself. You're *loading* the text here:

```
string scripts = file.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
```

... but then not using that variable. I suspect you wanted:

```
cmd.CommandText = scripts;
```

Note that using [`File.ReadAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext) would be considerably simpler than creating a new `FileInfo` etc:

```
string sql = File.ReadAllText(@"\\" + this.sc);
```

Also note that you should have `using` statements for your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` in order to close them properly if an exception is thrown.